# The current path, product/, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble with connecting to url code.

Everything is showing fine but after I tried to create, this error message pops up.

Also, I would like to know if path function works on the django 1.x.

'''error message'''

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/
Using the URLconf defined in seany.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^$
^register/$
^login/$
^product/create/
The current path, product/, didn't match any of these.
```

'''url.py'''

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from seany_user.views import index, registerview, loginview
from seany_product.views import productlist, productcreate
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', index),
    url(r'^register/$', registerview.as_view()),
    url(r'^login/$', loginview.as_view()),
    url(r'^product/create/', productcreate.as_view())
]
```

'''form.py'''

```
from django import forms
from seany_product.models import seanyproduct

class registerform(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
        error_messages={
            'required': 'enter your goddamn product'
        },
        max_length=64, label='product'
    )
    price = forms.IntegerField(
        error_messages={
            'required': 'enter your goddamn price'
        }, label='price'
    )
    description = forms.CharField(
        error_messages={
            'required': 'enter your goddamn description'
        }, label='description'
    )
    stock = forms.IntegerField(
        error_messages={
            'required': 'enter your goddamn stock'
        }, label='stock'
    )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        name = cleaned_data.get('name')
        price = cleaned_data.get('price')
        description = cleaned_data.get('description')
        stock = cleaned_data.get('stock')

        if name and price and description and stock:
            seany_product = product(
                name=name,
                price=price,
                description=description,
                stock=stock
            ) 
            seany_product.save()
```

'''views.py'''

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.shortcuts import render
from seany_product.models import seanyproduct
from seany_product.forms import registerform
# Create your views here.

class productlist(ListView):
    model = seanyproduct
    template_name = 'product.html'
    context_object_name = 'product_list'

class productcreate(FormView):
    template_name = 'register_product.html'
    form_class = registerform
    success_url = '/product/'
```

Comment: What is your question? As the error says, you don't have a URL for just "product/". Presumably you meant to link that to the productlist view.

Answer (score 0):

In the last piece of code, you are trying to direct to `/product/` url,

```
class productcreate(FormView):
    template_name = 'register_product.html'
    form_class = registerform
    success_url = '/product/' # <--- this
```

but in the urls.py `urlpatterns`, you have not defined any url `/product`. Note that `/product/create` is not same as `/product/`, which is why Django cannot find any thing in response to `/product` url, and returns 404 error.

To fix this, add a url in `urlpatterns` like -
`url(r'^product/$', productlist.as_view())`, or any other view as needed; you will also have to create this view.

Basically, Django does not know which page to show for `/product` url. You have to define that.